# Show object arraylist, inside a object arraylist in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

i want to show a object in a ArrayList that is inside a another ArrayList, example.

I can have 
in the Table,

- 0 10
- 0 20
- 0 30
- 1 40
- 1 50

I need to show all objects inside the ArrayList id. I need to repeat the same MecaId, for each OvoId in ArrayList

```
public class Meca {

    private ArrayList<Ovo> id;
    int idP=0;

    Ovo a;
    Ovo b;

    public Meca() {
        id = new ArrayList<Ovo>();
        a =  new Ovo(10);

        b = new Ovo(20);
        id.add(a);
        id.add(b);

    }
}

public class Ovo {

    int id;
    public Ovo(int id) {

    this.id = id;
}

public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        TableColumn<Meca,Integer> id = new TableColumn("ID Meca");
         id.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(data.getValue().getIdP()).asObject());

         TableColumn<Meca,Integer> idOvo = new TableColumn("ID Ovo");

             //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
             idOvo.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(data.getValue().getId().get(i).getId()).asObject());




         Meca y = new Meca();

         t.getColumns().addAll(id,idOvo);

        t.getItems().add(y);



}
```